# Copy File List off HDD and Browse it "Offline"

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, filesystems, file-management

I'm starting to loose track of which files I've put on which drives, and find myself needing to plug them in just to search for the files (by name).

Is there a tool that allows me copy and browse the folder names and structure along with the file names of the drive's contents, without having to copy the actual files' contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `robocopy` can do that. With the `/create` option, only zero-byte files are "copied".

Example: `robocopy D:\Data\ Z:\DataCopy\ /e /create`

I'm not sure how the `/mir` option behaves in this context, might be worth looking into to "update" the zero-byte copy.

Comment: Awesome. This was easier than I expected. 2 more questions then - when using /xd to exclude things, is valid to put other switches after that (e.g. use /xd and xf together), since /xd and /xf take variable numbers of arguments both. The documentation says that /tee prints a status progress - but I don't see anything.. Am I doing something wrong with `robocopy x:\ z:\dir /e /create /tee /xd recycler "system volume information"`?

Comment: `/tee` is defined as "output to console window, as well as the log file." – this is of course only useful when also using a log file. There's no overall progress indicator, if that's what you're looking for. Generally, arguments can be combined as desired. I also recommend excluding `$recycle.bin` by the way. :)